# Use Arithmetic Progression to find sum of multiples

Tags: c

I'm having some trouble with the arithmetic progression formula.

I'm attempting project Euler's problem #1 but on hackerranks website.

This is what i got :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

int test_cases, n;
char string[100];

fgets(string, 100, stdin);
sscanf(string, "%d", &test_cases);

while(test_cases--){
    fgets(string, 100, stdin);
    sscanf(string, "%d", &n);
    long long int sum = 0;

    long long int s1 = n / 3;
    long long int s2 = n / 5;
    long long int s3 = n / 15;

    long long int last_term_remainder_3 = n % 3;
    long long int last_term_remainder_5 = n % 5;
    long long int last_term_remainder_15 = n % 15;

    s1 = n % 3 == 0 ? s1 - 1 : s1;
    s2 = n % 5 == 0 ? s2 - 1 : s2;
    s3 = n % 15 == 0 ? s3 - 1 : s3;

    long long int last_term_3 = last_term_remainder_3 == 0 ? n - 3 : n - last_term_remainder_3;
    long long int last_term_5 = last_term_remainder_5 == 0 ? n - 5 : n - last_term_remainder_5;
    long long int last_term_15 = last_term_remainder_15 == 0 ? n - 15 : n - last_term_remainder_15;


    sum = (s1 * (3 + last_term_3)) / 2.0;
    sum += (s2 * (5 + last_term_5)) / 2.0;
    sum -= (s3 * (15 + last_term_15)) / 2.0;

    printf("%d\n", sum);
}

return 0;
}
```

I've read the Wikipedia page on the formula and have implemented it accordingly.
My solution solves the sample tests cases of 10 and 100, with 23 and 2318 as the answers respectfully.

It also solves the test cases 0,1,4 correctly, only giving me wrong answer on test cases 2 and 3.

On the website it was recommended to change the int's to `long long int`'s but that didn't help.

It was also recommended to check the edge cases when `n % 3 == 0`, `n % 5 == 0`, and `n % 15 == 0` which is why i have :

```
    s1 = n % 3 == 0 ? s1 - 1 : s1;
    s2 = n % 5 == 0 ? s2 - 1 : s2;
    s3 = n % 15 == 0 ? s3 - 1 : s3;
```

I can't see the test cases so i'm not sure where my program is going wrong. Any pointers as to what i can learn to figure out the answer is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: On one of the failed test cases it says : 0.03s Wrong answer. It doesn't give a time on the other failed case. It says wrong answer though and not anything related to time-out. And to the best of my knowledge this is an O(1) implementation and shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Oh, that actually makes a lot of sense. This solved my problem, thanks so much! Silly mistake :D

Answer (score 1):

`long long int sum = 0;` ... `printf("%d\n", sum);` is an error. Please use the `%lld` format specifier for `long long int` values. In addition, if you don't want negative values then perhaps you might benefit from using `unsigned long long int` instead (corresponding to `%llu`).